# Kali Linux for virtual box, screen size issue and fonts, everything appear to be very small

Tags: macos, resolution, virtualization, virtualbox

I tried into settings manager, but dint worked as expected. Even the terminal fonts aren't changing.[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120363/discussion-on-question-by-roshan-gami-kali-linux-for-virtual-box-screen-size-is).

Answer (score 4):

It would help if you specified an exact resolution or set a scaling factor to force either Kali or the virtualization to double (or more) the pixels on a Retina display.

In VBox, try the following;

1- Download and install Oracle VM VirtualBox Extension Pack from their official site [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads).

2- Open virtual box, go to preferences, go to display, then change the scale factor to either 150%, 200% or 300%, depending on your preferences.

[image]

3- Restart the running virtual machines.

Comment: Nice documentation - I wonder what OP meant by “I tried into settings manager, but dint worked as expected”

Comment: Saved my daycare